# Не работает вложенный цикл while c файлитератором

Tags: google-apps-script

Нужно из одной папки-источника на Г-драйве взять файлы по очереди и положить в другую папку, но только в том случае, если там нет файла с таким же названием.

Я решил реализовать задачу, используя вложенные циклы `while (sourceFiles.hasNext())`, однако, второй вложенный цикл работает только при первом проходе, затем перестает перебирать. Ощущение, что перебрав файлы один раз, он считает, что больше это делать не надо. С чем это может быть связано? Код ниже:

```
function  ExcelImport (){

        var sourceFolderId ='0B1Eh2NhtXvVISEZxRG5kSnJxcm8';   
        var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(sourceFolderId);
        var sourceFiles = sourceFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL);

        var destFolderId ='1MFTlcNQp8X2t65qCT7V1gINzXl0NYTER';
        var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destFolderId);
        var destFiles = destFolder.getFiles();//ByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS)

      while (sourceFiles.hasNext()) { // перебираем файлы в папаке-источнике
        var source = sourceFiles.next();
        var sourceId = source.getId();

        var fileName = source.getName().replace('.xlsx', '');
        var Flag="No";     
        while (destFiles.hasNext()) { //перебираем файлы в папке-назначения
           var dest = destFiles.next();
           var destFileName = dest.getName();
           if (fileName == destFileName){ // проверяем есть ли такой файл в папке назначения
             Flag = "Yes";       
             break;}
        }      
          if (Flag=="No"){ 
           var file = Drive.Files.copy({parents: [{id: destFolderId}]}, sourceId, {convert: true});
          }

      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

oshliaer, спасибо!

Я как чайник не совсем понял ваш вариант кода, поэтому не стал его проверять. Но я воспользовался вашей подсказкой и сделал все элегантно:

```
function  ExcelImport (){

    var sourceFolderId ='0B1Eh2NhtXvVISEZxRG5kSnJxcm8';    //задаем папку-источник
    var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(sourceFolderId);
    var sourceFiles = sourceFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL);
    var SourceArr = []; //создаем вспомогательный массив для записи данных файлов из папки-источника

    var destFolderId ='1MFTlcNQp8X2t65qCT7V1gINzXl0NYTER'; //задаем папку-назначения
    var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destFolderId);
    var destFiles = destFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS)

    while (sourceFiles.hasNext()) { // перебираем файлы в папаке-источнике и создаем вспомогательный массив SourceArr: ID файлы, имя файла, Yes/No       
        var source = sourceFiles.next();
        var sourceId = source.getId();
        var fileName = source.getName().replace('.xlsx', '');
        var SourcePush = [sourceId, fileName, "Yes"];
        SourceArr.push(SourcePush); 
        }     

    while (destFiles.hasNext()) { //перебираем файлы в папке назначения
      var dest = destFiles.next(); 
      var destFileName = dest.getName();
      SourceArr.forEach(function(Sourceitem) { // перебираем вспомогательный массив        
        if (Sourceitem [1] == destFileName) {Sourceitem [2]  = "No";} // проверяем есть ли такой файл в папке назначения, если есть, то в источнике ставим No для копирования
       })
    } 

    SourceArr.forEach(function(Sourceitem) { // перебираем вспомогательный массив, если значение в записи Yes, то копируем файл по ID из вспомогательного массива
      if (Sourceitem[2] =="Yes"){var file = Drive.Files.copy({parents: [{id: destFolderId}]}, Sourceitem[0], {convert: true});}
    })
 }
```